# Sqlite3 Insertion does not retain records with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I am trying to insert multiple records to sqlite database. This is my test script.

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
company = 'fghjk'
keyword = 'awesome'
filename = 'test.txt'
date_found = datetime.now()
conn = sqlite3.connect('C:\\sqlite\\test.db')
c = conn.cursor()

for i in range(0,4):
    insert_query = "INSERT into records (company,keyword,filename,date_found) values (?,?,?,?)"
    c.execute(insert_query, [company,keyword,filename,date_found])

select_query  = "SELECT * FROM records"
c.execute(select_query)
res = c.fetchall()
print res
for i in res:
    for b in i:
        print b
```

When I execute the script above **twice**, I am expecting to have 8 records, but it's always giving back 4 rows. Can someone enlighten me?

Output:

```
1
fghjk
awesome
test.txt
2016-09-23 09:11:19.585000
2
fghjk
awesome
test.txt
2016-09-23 09:11:19.585000
3
fghjk
awesome
test.txt
2016-09-23 09:11:19.585000
4
fghjk
awesome
test.txt
2016-09-23 09:11:19.585000
```

This is my table's create statement.

```
conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE records
      # (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
       # company           TEXT    NOT NULL,
       # keyword            INT     NOT NULL,
       # filename        CHAR(50),
       # date_found        DATETIME);''')
```

Comment: Did you try closing the connection at the end of the script? It can be more easily achieved by wrapping all code that uses the connection with `with conn:`. I run it like this and see no issues.

Comment: i did add the `close()`at the end of the script. Still same result. Would u mind posting an answer? Thank you. @PaulRooney

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem looks to be that you're not committing the data to the database.

Each time you open the database, you put in 4 rows, then print them, then let the cursor and connection be destroyed without committing your changes.

Calling `conn.commit()` after all of your inserts are done will fix this.  IIRC, the table creation is automatically committed immediately after it runs, which is why it is saved in the database.

Comment: oh wow. yea. you're right. I forgot the commit. Thank you! @cco

Answer (score 3):

You can use the connection as a context manager. This will properly terminate the connection, including a commit.

```
import sqlite3
from datetime import datetime
company = 'fghjk'
keyword = 'awesome'
filename = 'test.txt'
date_found = datetime.now()
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
first = False

# use context manager here!!
with conn:
    c = conn.cursor()
    if first:
        conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE records
            (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            company           TEXT    NOT NULL,
            keyword            INT     NOT NULL,
            filename        CHAR(50),
            date_found        DATETIME);''')

    for i in range(0,4):
        insert_query = "INSERT into records (company,keyword,filename,date_found) values (?,?,?,?)"
        c.execute(insert_query, [company,keyword,filename,date_found])

    select_query  = "SELECT * FROM records"
    c.execute(select_query)
    res = c.fetchall()
    print res
    for i in res:
        for b in i:
        print b
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! @Paul